# First Azure Deployment - Intellitrace has tonnes of exceptions

Tags: azure

I enabled IntelliTrace on an ASP.NET MVC2 app that seems to working very well in the staging area. My app talks to a SQL Azure database, and everything's running smoothly, but the intellitrace log is filled with Exceptions. Some of those are obvious MVC2 messages (like an exception about not being able to find a file in the controller's view folder, but it finds it in the Shared folder instead... ), but some have me a little worried. Should I be?

See the attached screenshot.

[image]

Bottom Line - should the tracelog be filled with garbage like this or am I doing something silly?

Comment: Probably a dumb question but did you change your service configuration to re-point DiagnosticsConnectionString and DataConnectionString to Azure storage instead of development storage?

Comment: Hey, Denis, wanna make a quick "accepted Answer"? (* blush *)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, here is a repost so everyone with a similar issue can find the solution.. After you've deployed your application don't forget to adjust configuration settings DiagnosticsConnectionString and DataConnectionString to re-point them to the actual Azure storage instead of development storage.